# Angular $http.post() request sent as OPTIONS to IdentityServer v3 Token Endpoint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, openid-connect, identityserver3

I have a sample app to Authorize using IdentityServer v3 and OpenID Connect Authorization Code Flow in client side. I can successfully get the `authorization_code` and the `session_state` but when i call the token endpoint a problem occurs. Token Endpoint responds with `Invalid HTTP status code 405`

Here is the code for the Angular.js config.

**Angular.js**

***app.js***

```js
angular.module('oidc3', ['oauth', 'ngStorage', 'base64'])
    .config(function ($locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = false;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    });
```

***loginController***

```js
angular.module('oidc3')
    .controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $location, $base64) {

    var getParamsFromUrl = function(url) {
        var splitted = url.split('?');
        splitted = splitted[1].split('&');
        var params = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
            var param  = splitted[i].split('=');
            var key    = param[0];
            var value  = param[1];
            params[key] = value
        }
        return params;
    };

    var getToken = function (url, data, header) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = header;
        return $http.post(url, data);
    };

    if($location.absUrl().split('?')[1]) {
        $scope.params = getParamsFromUrl($location.absUrl());

        var tokenEndpoint = 'https://localhost:44333/connect/token';
        var client_id = 'codeclient';
        var client_secret = 'secret';
        var str = client_id + ':' + client_secret;

        var baseEncoded = $base64.encode(str);    


        var tokenData = {};
        tokenData.grant_type = 'authorization_code';
        tokenData.code = $scope.params.code;
        tokenData.redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000/login.html';


        var reqHeader = 'Basic ' + baseEncoded;

        getToken(tokenEndpoint, tokenData, reqHeader)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(headers);
                console.log(config);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(headers);
                console.log(config);
            });
    }
});
```

I am manually setting the Authorization headers to `Basic` with the encoded `client_id` and `client_secret`. When the POST request is sent the server returns a 405 response. Screen grab of the Chrome Developer tools Network section is here.

[image]

But when i don't manually set the header the POST request is sent correctly and the server returns a `invalid_client` error because it doesn't have a way to authenticate the client with out the Header. The IdentityServer v3 Trace.log messages are bellow.

**With Manually Set Authorization Header**

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.WelcomeController]: 4/29/2015 3:34:19 AM +00:00 -- Welcome page requested
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.WelcomeController]: 4/29/2015 3:34:19 AM +00:00 -- Rendering welcome page
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointController]: 4/29/2015 3:34:34 AM +00:00 -- Start authorize request
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:34:34 AM +00:00 -- Start authorize request protocol validation
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:34:34 AM +00:00 -- Authorize request validation success
 {
  "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
  "ResponseType": "code",
  "ResponseMode": "query",
  "Flow": "AuthorizationCode",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile email",
  "State": "1430278473164",
  "Nonce": "nonce",
  "SessionId": "585c26034281e898b73012e9335868cb",
  "Raw": {
    "response_type": "code",
    "client_id": "codeclient",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "state": "1430278473164",
    "nonce": "nonce"
  }
}
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:34:34 AM +00:00 -- Start authorize request client validation
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:34:34 AM +00:00 -- Authorize request validation success
 {
  "ClientId": "codeclient",
  "ClientName": "Code Flow Client Demo",
  "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "https://localhost:44312/callback",
    "http://localhost:63342/oidc_test/redirect.html",
    "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
    "https://localhost:4443/login.html"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "88421113",
  "ResponseType": "code",
  "ResponseMode": "query",
  "Flow": "AuthorizationCode",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile email",
  "State": "1430278473164",
  "Nonce": "nonce",
  "SessionId": "585c26034281e898b73012e9335868cb",
  "Raw": {
    "response_type": "code",
    "client_id": "codeclient",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "state": "1430278473164",
    "nonce": "nonce"
  }
}
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointController]: 4/29/2015 3:34:34 AM +00:00 -- Showing consent screen
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointController]: 4/29/2015 3:34:34 AM +00:00 -- End authorize request
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointController]: 4/29/2015 3:34:36 AM +00:00 -- Resuming from consent, restarting validation
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:34:36 AM +00:00 -- Start authorize request protocol validation
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:34:36 AM +00:00 -- Authorize request validation success
 {
  "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
  "ResponseType": "code",
  "ResponseMode": "query",
  "Flow": "AuthorizationCode",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile email",
  "State": "1430278473164",
  "Nonce": "nonce",
  "SessionId": "585c26034281e898b73012e9335868cb",
  "Raw": {
    "response_type": "code",
    "client_id": "codeclient",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "state": "1430278473164",
    "nonce": "nonce"
  }
}
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:34:36 AM +00:00 -- Start authorize request client validation
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:34:36 AM +00:00 -- Authorize request validation success
 {
  "ClientId": "codeclient",
  "ClientName": "Code Flow Client Demo",
  "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "https://localhost:44312/callback",
    "http://localhost:63342/oidc_test/redirect.html",
    "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
    "https://localhost:4443/login.html"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "88421113",
  "ResponseType": "code",
  "ResponseMode": "query",
  "Flow": "AuthorizationCode",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile email",
  "State": "1430278473164",
  "Nonce": "nonce",
  "SessionId": "585c26034281e898b73012e9335868cb",
  "Raw": {
    "response_type": "code",
    "client_id": "codeclient",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "state": "1430278473164",
    "nonce": "nonce"
  }
}
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator]: 4/29/2015 3:34:36 AM +00:00 -- Creating Authorization Code Flow response.
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Results.AuthorizeRedirectResult]: 4/29/2015 3:34:36 AM +00:00 -- Redirecting to: http://localhost:8000/login.html
```

**Without Manually Setting Authorization Header**

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.WelcomeController]: 4/29/2015 3:37:39 AM +00:00 -- Welcome page requested
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.WelcomeController]: 4/29/2015 3:37:39 AM +00:00 -- Rendering welcome page
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointController]: 4/29/2015 3:37:52 AM +00:00 -- Start authorize request
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:37:52 AM +00:00 -- Start authorize request protocol validation
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:37:52 AM +00:00 -- Authorize request validation success
 {
  "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
  "ResponseType": "code",
  "ResponseMode": "query",
  "Flow": "AuthorizationCode",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile email",
  "State": "1430278670509",
  "Nonce": "nonce",
  "SessionId": "585c26034281e898b73012e9335868cb",
  "Raw": {
    "response_type": "code",
    "client_id": "codeclient",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "state": "1430278670509",
    "nonce": "nonce"
  }
}
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:37:52 AM +00:00 -- Start authorize request client validation
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:37:52 AM +00:00 -- Authorize request validation success
 {
  "ClientId": "codeclient",
  "ClientName": "Code Flow Client Demo",
  "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "https://localhost:44312/callback",
    "http://localhost:63342/oidc_test/redirect.html",
    "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
    "https://localhost:4443/login.html"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "88421113",
  "ResponseType": "code",
  "ResponseMode": "query",
  "Flow": "AuthorizationCode",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile email",
  "State": "1430278670509",
  "Nonce": "nonce",
  "SessionId": "585c26034281e898b73012e9335868cb",
  "Raw": {
    "response_type": "code",
    "client_id": "codeclient",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "state": "1430278670509",
    "nonce": "nonce"
  }
}
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointController]: 4/29/2015 3:37:52 AM +00:00 -- Showing consent screen
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointController]: 4/29/2015 3:37:52 AM +00:00 -- End authorize request
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointController]: 4/29/2015 3:37:54 AM +00:00 -- Resuming from consent, restarting validation
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:37:54 AM +00:00 -- Start authorize request protocol validation
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:37:54 AM +00:00 -- Authorize request validation success
 {
  "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
  "ResponseType": "code",
  "ResponseMode": "query",
  "Flow": "AuthorizationCode",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile email",
  "State": "1430278670509",
  "Nonce": "nonce",
  "SessionId": "585c26034281e898b73012e9335868cb",
  "Raw": {
    "response_type": "code",
    "client_id": "codeclient",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "state": "1430278670509",
    "nonce": "nonce"
  }
}
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:37:54 AM +00:00 -- Start authorize request client validation
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:37:54 AM +00:00 -- Authorize request validation success
 {
  "ClientId": "codeclient",
  "ClientName": "Code Flow Client Demo",
  "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "https://localhost:44312/callback",
    "http://localhost:63342/oidc_test/redirect.html",
    "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
    "https://localhost:4443/login.html"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "88421113",
  "ResponseType": "code",
  "ResponseMode": "query",
  "Flow": "AuthorizationCode",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile email",
  "State": "1430278670509",
  "Nonce": "nonce",
  "SessionId": "585c26034281e898b73012e9335868cb",
  "Raw": {
    "response_type": "code",
    "client_id": "codeclient",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8000/login.html",
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "state": "1430278670509",
    "nonce": "nonce"
  }
}
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator]: 4/29/2015 3:37:54 AM +00:00 -- Creating Authorization Code Flow response.
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Results.AuthorizeRedirectResult]: 4/29/2015 3:37:54 AM +00:00 -- Redirecting to: http://localhost:8000/login.html
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController]: 4/29/2015 3:37:55 AM +00:00 -- Start token request
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.ClientValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:37:55 AM +00:00 -- Start client validation
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Validation.ClientValidator]: 4/29/2015 3:37:55 AM +00:00 -- No or malformed client credential found.
 {}
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController]: 4/29/2015 3:37:55 AM +00:00 -- End token request
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Results.TokenErrorResult]: 4/29/2015 3:37:55 AM +00:00 -- Returning error: invalid_client
```

I did some research and found out that this is related to CORS and this is due to a preflight check to see if my client can access the endpoint i'm calling. How can i avoid this and send the POST request as it is to the Token Endpoint.